# How to train an ML model to convert the given lyrics into a song by a particular singer?

Tags: machine-learning, reference-request, algorithm-request, model-request

I am interested in training a machine algorithm to convert the lyrics I give into a song by a particular singer.

My language is non-English (south Indian) The songs are mostly monophonic (very few instruments, if at all). I have data of a bunch of songs sung by this singer, I want to try new lyrics and imagine how to singer would have sung.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenAI used a modified version of VQ-VAE-2 combined with sparse transformers to do something similar to what you want to do. Their approach, called [Jukebox](https://openai.com/blog/jukebox/), is able to produce music by conditioning on certain styles, lyrics, and artists, which you might explore to do what you want. You can explore [here](https://jukebox.openai.com/?song=787749904) the produced songs. For example, the model was able to produce [a hip-hop song that uses the lyrics of Eminem's Lose Yourself, but with a Kanye West's style](https://soundcloud.com/openai_audio/jukebox-905633287). You can find the original research paper [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.00341) and the associated codebase [here](https://github.com/openai/jukebox/).